# Spring integration heap space error, when read large csv file from ftp

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have problem with spring integration when reading large csv file from ftp. the csv file have 1.5 million row.

here is my configuration

```
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow automaticRouteFlow() {
    return p -> p
        .transform(unZipTransformer(), e -> e.advice())
        .split(new UnZipResultSplitter())
        .enrichHeaders(s -> s.headerExpressions(h -> h
            .put(FtpConstant.UNCOMPRESSED_DIR, "payload.getParentFile()")
            .put(FtpConstant.UNCOMPRESSED_FILE, "payload"))
            .header(FtpConstant.FAILED_PATH, failedDirectory)
        )
        .split(Files.splitter(true), e -> e.advice(fileHandlerAdvice()))
        .transform(o -> {
              try {
                return routeManagementTransformer.transform(o.toString());
              } catch (Exception e) {
                return new PollSkipAdvice();
              }
            }
        )
        .transform(Transformers.toJson())
        .filter(o -> !o.toString().equals("{}"))
        .channel(MessageChannels.queue())
        .handle(kafkaMessageHandler(kafkaTemplate, topic),
            e -> {
              e.poller(
                  Pollers.fixedDelay(queueFixDelay).maxMessagesPerPoll(queueMaxMessagesPerPoll));
              e.advice(directoryHandler());
            }
        );
  }
```

I set 5 queueMaxMessagesPerPoll , and i validate null and empty data every row in routeManagementTransformer.transform, there is no pulling to database. it just validate not null and not blank in every rows
is there any problem in my code?.

Comment: Please, show how you read files from FTP. Right now we only see that you already unzipping them and try to send to Kafka. Although I don't see reason in that queue channel before sending to Kafka...

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan thanks for your response. actually i already solved my problem. i change the message channel queue to MessageChannels.publishSubscribe(). and it works fine. and it can handle more than 5 milion data.